# Attach/Stick a UIButton under the UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

This illustration shows what i'm trying to do:
[image]

The green list is the UITableView where it dynamically adjust it's height based on the number of items inside of it.
Underneath of the UITableView is a button that should follow the UITableView whenever it changes it's height size.

The UIButton should always be beneath the UITableView whatever the size of the UItableView.

I'm currently using autoresizing for UITableView
[image]

I have tried to use Autolayout but it seems i can't still find the answer.
i currently have no constraints in the layout.

Answer (score 0):

This boils down to calculating the height of the table view that perfectly fits the cells. Basically you need to measure the size of every cell, then create a height constraint on the table view, and set its constant to the sum of the cells' heights.

Measuring the height of cells is tricky thought. If you only have a few cells (like in your illustrations), you can just instantiate all of them, keep them in an array and use `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` to calculate their sizes. If you use multi-line labels, it is also important to set their `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` to appropriate values.

However, if you have only a few cells (and so cell reuse is not important), stack view is probably a better choice than table view. It's just too tricky to calculate the perfect height of a table view.

Comment: i have about 8 - 9 cells, the only problem i have now is to stick the uibutton on the footer of the uitableview.